# Filling under a curve without boundary

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill the region under the curve but with no other boundary. Here is what I tried.

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw [-, ] (-3,0) --(-0.4,0);
   \draw [-, ] (0.4,0) --(3,0);

   \draw [blue,thick,domain=180:360] plot ({.4*cos(\x)}, {.4*sin(\x)});

   \fill [color=gray, opacity=0.1](-3,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,-3) -- (-3,-3);
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to draw. Can you post an image with at least a rough sense of what you want to obtain?

Comment: above the arc shouldn't be gray

Comment: try this `\fill [color=gray, opacity=.1] (-3,0) -- plot[domain=180:360] ({.4*cos(\x)}, {.4*sin(\x)}) -- (3,0) -- (3,-3) -- (-3,-3);`

Comment: @Kpym Actually I want that horizontal boundary. Please have a look at my added picture.

Comment: But this is generated with your MWE. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't want the circular region to be filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or without plot function, by using `arc`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=1mm,
               preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray!10]  ( -3,-3) |- (-0.4,0) arc (-180:0:4mm) -| (3,-3);
\draw ( -3,0) -- (-0.4,0)  (0.4,0) -- ( 3.0,0);
\draw [blue,thick] (-0.4,0) arc  (-180:0:4mm);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]